# Android. How to load the picture from memory knowing its full path?

Tags: android, file, bitmap

I saved the picture on phone from application. I found a file manager it and I made sure that it really remained. Further I try to load on its full path it by **BitmapFactory.decodeFile()** method transferring a full path to the picture, a way to pictures at me such there, I will give an example from application:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com .example.home.page/files/2015218161530.jpg`

But me jumps out Exception, what decoding is impossible since the file isn't found, what for nonsense? Thanks in advance

Comment: jumps out Exception...what is the exception?

Comment: Is the **space** in the path a typo?

Comment: First, ALWAYS post the logcat.  Secondly, do you have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?  And if so, what version of Android are you on?  If its 4.4 or later and your app is not com.example,home.page you won't have permission to read that file.

Comment: 03-19 13:25:23.601  26525-26525/com.example.home.page E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.graphics.Bitmap@240fea0d: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-19 13:25:23.601  26525-26525/com.example.home.page I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@240fea0d

Comment: I stated permission in the manifesto for a read and write of external data

Answer (score 0):

try below code that might help you.

```
File f = new File(PathToFiles +yourFileName);
if (f.exists()) {
  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getPath());
  imageview.setImageDrawable(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method this will work for you
just pass path of images(where your image is store and object reference of you ImageView as a second argument)

```
1st argument Path of images want ot display
2nd argument object reference of `ImageView`

public static void ShowPicture(String filePath, ImageView pic) { 
    File f = new File(filePath); 
    FileInputStream is = null; 
    try { 
        is = new FileInputStream(f); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("error: ",String.format( "ShowPicture.java file[%s]Not Found",fileName)); 
        return; 
    } 

    Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, null); 
    pic.setImageBitmap(bm); 
}
```

please also put this permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```